# Map with media texture not packaging

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, 360-video

I have a simple map with a Big-sphere and a pawn inside it. I use media texture and media player to play 360 video on it. But when I try to package it for windows-64 it fails while it tries to cook the map.

Yes all the videos are copied to Content/Movies first and then imported to UEProject as asset later.

This is very crucial to our project. One of our developer have already started to build the solution in Unity just in case if packaging issue does not resolve with media player in unreal.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some problems with media textures, file formats and memory size:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/378202/media-texture-not-showing-in-umg-after-packaging.html

Please paste the packaging failure message, it should help identify the problem.